# Decodable & Enum Values

Tags: swift, decodable

How should I handle the situation where an enum value does not exist when decoding an object? For example, how would I handle the case where "horrible" is the rating type in the example below? Is there a way to set a default value if none of the values exist?

```
public struct Review: Decodable {

    public var ratingType: RatingType?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ratingType = "rating_type"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        ratingType = try container.decodeIfPresent(RatingType.self, forKey: .ratingType)
    }
}

public enum RatingType: String, Codable {
    case Good = "good"
    case Bad = "bad"
}
```

Comment: If the value is "horrible" then it will throw an error. I suppose you can catch that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decodeIfPresent` returns `nil` if the key is not present, and it will likely throw an error if the value is invalid. By using `try?`, we can do this:

```
ratingType = 
    (try? (container.decodeIfPresent(RatingType.self, forKey: .ratingType) ?? <some default value>)
    ) ?? <some default value>
```

Comment: One can decode without overriding required init with decoder method. Is there any way to tell the decoder that it will use 'try?' instead of 'try' while decodeIfPresent is doing. In my case i'm dealing with structs with lots of properties, it is quiet tedious to implement required init with decoder and CodingKeys and mapping each values to each property. So is there any way to tell JSONDecoder to use try? instead of try while decoding from container ?

Answer (score 1):

In the case that the received unexpected rating should be actually used (defensive coding against a version mismatch between client and server or whatever) you can try with a different enum definition:

```
enum RatingType
{
    case good
    case bad
    case other(String)
}
```

You lose the automatic encoding but gain flexibility.

A possible implementation:

```
import Foundation

struct Review
{
    public var rating: RatingType?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rating = "rating_type"
    }

    public init(rating: RatingType) {
        self.rating = rating
    }
}

extension Review: Decodable
{
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let label = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .rating) {
            rating = RatingType(label: label)
        }
    }
}

extension Review: Encodable
{
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let rating = rating {
            try container.encode(rating.label, forKey: .rating)
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
enum RatingType
{
    case good
    case bad
    case other(String)

    init(label: String) {
        switch label {
            case "good": self = .good
            case "bad": self = .bad
            default: self = .other(label)
        }
    }

    var label: String {
        switch self {
            case .bad: return "bad"
            case .good: return "good"
            case let .other(label): return label
        }
    }
}
```

In real life you may want to make `RatingType` conforming to `Codable`/`Decodable` instead, simplifying the coding/encoding. Feel free to modify.

An example exercising the encoding/decoding:

```
func encode_review(_ review: Review) throws -> String
{
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(review)
    return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "/* ERROR */"
}

func decode_json(_ json: String) throws -> Review?
{
    guard let data = json.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return nil }
    let review = try JSONDecoder().decode(Review.self, from: data)
    return review
}

print(try! encode_review(Review(rating: .good)))  // {"rating_type":"good"}
print(try! encode_review(Review(rating: .other("horrible")))) // {"rating_type":"horrible"}

let good_review_json = """
    {"rating_type":"good"}
"""
let great_review_json = """
    {"rating_type":"great"}
"""

if let review = try! decode_json(good_review_json), let label = review.rating?.label {
    print(label) // good
}
if let review = try! decode_json(great_review_json), let label = review.rating?.label {
    print(label) // great
}
```